# Eclipse e4 : IStartup extension not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno, e4

I am trying to extending "org.eclipse.ui.startup" extendion point.
 but it seems in eclipse e4 ,it does not even getting called.
is this extension is broken in eclipse e4(Juno)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and couldn't find an answer, but in the process I discovered the LifeCycleHandler which is even better for my purpose. It might be a good alternative for you as well.

Just as with the startup-extension you can reference a handler from your plugin.xml:

```
<property name="lifeCycleURI" value="platform:/plugin/<plug-in-id>/<path-to-handler-class>" />
```

In the handler you can use annotations to mark the method that is to be invoked as well as dependency injection:

```
public class StartupHandler {
    @Inject
    Foo bar;

    @PostContextCreate
    public void startup(IEclipseContext context) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

You can find a detailed example here: https://marcteufel.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/231/

Answer (score 1):

IStartup#earlyStartup() needs the compatibility layer, so it does not work in a pure E4 Application. (see [#1](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html))

To launch a process in a pure E4 Application you should use a lifecycle hook. So:

Reference your ApplicationLifecycle handler class from plugin.xml

```
<property name="lifeCycleURI" value="platform:/plugin/<plug-in-id>/<path-to-handler-class>" />
```

write your lifecycle handler class

```
public class ApplicationLifecycleHandler {

    @PostContextCreate
    public void startup(IEclipseContext context) {
       // do initialization 
    }
}
```

Add an hook to handle events at Application Startup Complete

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate(final IEventBroker eventBroker, etc .. ) {

    // 
    eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE,
            new EventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                    // Your code executed at startup,
                    // after application startup is completed
                }
            });

}
```

(#1) [org.eclipse.ui.startup extension doc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html)

Comment: Hi @psuzzi, can you pls tell me more about the compatibility layer you mentioned in your comment. I have a similar issue but cannot edit the plugin code. So I was wondering if putting some compatibilty plugins can help me get it working with e4Application. Thanks